# Error message with web site in Tuleap project

Tags: website, tuleap

I installed Tuleap on a server and add a new project. However when I click on the "Site Web" link to see the web site linked to the project, I get the following error message: Sorry, page not found.
In the /var/log/httpd/error_log file there is the following error message:
[Fri Feb 12 09:11:33 2016] [error] [client 132.166.150.1] File does not exist: /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/www, referer: https://is149532
.intra.cea.fr/project/admin/?group_id=113

What is wrong in my Tuleap configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should uncomment the website section at the beginning of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/codendi_aliases.conf`

Be careful, there is no isolation at all between pages & users used for pages management hence you should only allow this feature for users you trust 100%

Comment: You can "validate" the response if it works (good for karma) ;)